# Terraform data source List and Filter Existing Azure Resource Group

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I want to List existing resource groups with terraform in azure and filter them based on their certain tags, is this possible? I can only input the name of a single Resource Group using resource group data source below:

```
data "azurerm_resource_group" "existingRG" {
  name = "existingRGname"
}

output "id" {
  value = data.azurerm_resource_group.existingRG.id
}
```

I want something like:

```
data "azurerm_resource_group" "existingRGs" {
  name = "*"

required_tags = {
    environment = "production"
    role        = "webserver"
  }

}


output "ids" {
  value = data.azurerm_resource_group.*.id
}
```

I don't mind if powershell provisioner is used for this or any other approach as long as it returns filtered resource groups in the output, I did not see any options in the terraform docs. There is one for resources but it does not pick resource groups.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar use case and made a solution based off the [external provider](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/external/latest/docs/data-sources/external) as mentioned in another comment, PowerShell, and Azure Resource Graph.

As it uses Resource Graph queries it can naturally be used for a lot more than just resource groups.

Example (simplified):

**Module**

external_data.tf

```
data "external" "resources" {
  program = [
    "pwsh",
    "${path.module}/scripts/resourceGraph.ps1", 
    var.resource_graph_query
  ]
}

output "resources" {
  value = data.external.resources.result
}
```

**resourceGraph.ps1**

Return key/value pairs as required by the external provider

```
$obj = New-Object PSObject
  $result = (Search-AzGraph -Query $Query -First 1000)
  foreach ($resource in $result) {
      $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $resource.Name -Value $resource.Id
  }
  $obj | ConvertTo-Json
```

**Use the module**

```
# Get resources
module "rg_resources" {
  source = "../modules/get_resources"

  script_name          = "resourceGraph.ps1"
  resource_graph_query = "resourcecontainers | where type == 'microsoft.resources/subscriptions/resourcegroups' | where tostring(tags.mytag) =~ 'hello_world' | project name, id"

}


# Read into Terraform Data Source for further processing, if needed
# Use either azapi or azurerm
data "azapi_resource" "this" {

  for_each = module.rg_resources.resources

  type        = "Microsoft.Resources/resourceGroups@2022-09-01"
  resource_id = each.value

  response_export_values = ["*"]

}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because such functionality does not exist. You have to implement it yourself in your own [custom data source](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/external/latest/docs).

Comment: That link currently 404s.

Comment: @WaitingForGuacamole The link works now.